# Get all document in opensearch

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, opensearch

I am using opensearchpy and I want to get a field called model that  is not found in all document so I can know which models are stored there , is there is way to go over all document and get thie one field and return it in the response ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to search for the documents that have this "model" field. Through [Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) you can filter documents with this field.

```
query = {
  'query': {
    'exists': {
      'field': 'model'
    }
  }
}
response = client.search(
    body = query,
    index = index_name
)
```

Comment: How to use that with opensearchpy  ?